# Why am I receiving "build failed with an exception" when I run projects in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[Android studio window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFbYL.png)

I've tried running a flutter project on Android Studio and it keeps giving me this error. Pleases I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a connection problem, it could happen if you are using a vpn and it's not giving you stable internet connection. make sure that android studio is connected to a stable internet.